# Static Column while sorting a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a few Columns. There is no DataTable bound to it.
All values are inserted once after the start and stay then as they are.

The user should be able to sort by all Columns, except for the first one.
The first Column should always show the index (1 for the first row, 2 for the second one and so on).

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Paint the Row Index in the RowHeader Cell. Or freeze a standard Column and paint the *number* in there instead.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jimi, I implemented this solution:

```
private StringFormat sfRight = new StringFormat () { Alignment = StringAlignment.Far };

private void ..._CellPainting (object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.PaintBackground (e.ClipBounds, true);
        e.Graphics.DrawString ((e.RowIndex + 1).ToString (), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.White, e.CellBounds.X + e.CellBounds.Width - 4, e.CellBounds.Y + 4, sfRight);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```